# multiprocessing pool with map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I try to multiprocess my code like this:

```
param_seq = []
pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)

def work(param_set):
    (_, v) = experiment_sim(param_set[0], param_set[1])
    v_dev = np.subtract(exp_v, v)
    return - np.sum(np.square(v_dev)) / (2 * noise_sigma ** 2)

for x in Ra.values:
    for y in gpas.values:
        param_seq.append((x, y))

likelihood = pool.map(work, param_seq)
```

And it looks working fine, do all the work, but in the and it stops and do nothing and I have to stop the program. Then to following message occurs:

```
Process PoolWorker-8:
Process PoolWorker-10:
Process PoolWorker-13:
Process PoolWorker-14:
Process PoolWorker-11:
Process PoolWorker-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self.run()
    self.run()
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    task = get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    task = get()
    task = get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    task = get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    task = get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    racquire()
    racquire()
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    racquire()
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

**Edit:**
It finishes the computations, but can't give back the result list. The is program terminated at that point forever.

**Edit:**
This solved almost the issue:

```
# Multi processing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    likelihood = pool.map(work2, param_seq)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

But if I use it for heavy computation, the whole thing crashes:

```
def work2(param_set):
    (_, v) = experiment_sim(param_set[0], param_set[1])
    v_dev = np.array(np.subtract(exp_v, v))
    return - 1 / 2 * np.dot(v_dev, invcovmat.dot(v_dev))
```

Where invcovmat is a huge matrix! Is there any idea how to solve the problem?

The crash report:

```
Process:               Python [51365]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.11 (2.7.11)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [49361]
Responsible:           Python [51365]
User ID:               502
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000110
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

.
.
.
Application Specific Information:
*** multi-threaded process forked ***
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec
```

Comment: Although it looks like you're using Linux, so shouldn't need to do so, try putting the code from the `for` loop onward inside of an `if __name__ == '__main__':` conditional. This allows the code to be imported safely by subprocesses. This is explained in the Windows section of the [multiprocessing programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

Comment: Thanks the reply, but it not solved the issue! The same strange thing happening again. So it finishes the computation and gives back the values, but than it do nothing, the code is not running further.

Comment: Oh it seems it is indeed the solution! Thanks

Comment: That's good to hear and you're welcome. It was just a long shot, but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: However sometimes it crashes when I pass huge arrays to the worker function. I don't know whether there is a safe solutions...

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Python? The 32-bit version has 4 GB memory limit.

Comment: Yes it is! But the invcovmat matrix is loaded from a 2GB file, so I guess it can't handle that.

Comment: 64-bit Python should be able to handle it, although it could become really slow if you don't have enough real memory and start using disk-based virtual.memory). The problem could be a bad pointer in the C code of the `np` module.

Comment: And what do you think, how cold I avoid the issue? Try to find other package than numpy?

Comment: If there's an alternative package, by all means try it. Another alternative might be to keep using `numpy`, but use a slightly different, but mathematically equivalent, method to compute the desired values.

Comment: I could only solve the issue with taking apart the computation and the last part with big matrix multiplication is solved with map function without multiprocessing. Not the best, but it is way faster even this way! Thanks your help, you are really kind! :)